# How to create an XML File and Host It?

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, api, cloud, dropbox

I am getting an XML Data from an API. Now with this data i want to create an XML Doc from the API Data. I tried with Google Doc API's but Google saves at docx and not XML. Does AWS has a product through which i can create a doc and host it?

I have tried Google Drive API's but it saves as DocX. I have tried with Dropbox, but it saves as txt file only.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this use case by dynamically writing an XML document using a given API such as [Interface Document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html). Then use a supported AWS SDK such as the AWS SDK for Java to upload this to an AMazon S3 Bucket. This solves your hosting requirement.

You can even do all of this from an AWS Lambda function. So yes - AWS Supports this use case via its AWS SDK with some custom programming.